# WebSockets with nginx and puma (websocket-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket, puma

Using the [websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails) gem, I'm able to successfully get a websocket connection straight through puma in development, however, when deployed to production and attempting to access the websocket through nginx (passing off to puma) I have a couple of errors: one in the nginx error log:

```
[info] 14340#0: *7 upstream timed out (110: Connection 
timed out) while proxying upgraded connection, client: 123.45.67.89, server: 
foo.com, request: "GET /websocket HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://unix:///opt/oneconnect/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/websocket", host: 
"foo.com"
```

... and one on the javascript console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://foo.com/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301
```

I found that nginx (the version I'm using is 1.4.6) is capable of websocket use but [requires special configuration](http://nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/), which I've already attemped (getting the errors above). Here's my nginx.conf:

```
upstream oneconnect {
        server unix:///opt/oneconnect/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        #ssl on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/foo.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/foo.com.key;

        root /opt/oneconnect/current/public;
        try_files $uri @oneconnect;

        access_log /opt/oneconnect/current/log/nginx.access.log;
        error_log /opt/oneconnect/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

        server_name foo.com;

        location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
          root /opt/oneconnect/current/public;
          gzip_static on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location /websocket/ {
            proxy_pass http://oneconnect;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location @oneconnect {
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://oneconnect;
        }
}
```

I'm assuming that I'm missing something simple, but I'm stumped at this point and have Googled until my eyes started bleeding. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated, or maybe just point me to how to debug these connections (it seems hard to get debug info from a ws connection). Thanks for your time.

Comment: you use `ssl` for `websocket`?

Comment: No SSL as far as I can tell. `ws://foo.com/websocket` is the URL so I don't think that's SSL unless I'm missing something.

Comment: i'm not sure but if proxy server `nginx` pass all traffic trough `ssl` then `ws://foo.com/websocket` not avaliable, so `ws://foo.com/websocket` should be under `ssl` too(`wss://foo.com/websocket`). IMO

Comment: The nginx server is listening via SSL but the `proxy_pass` directive in the configuration indicates `http://` and the SSL certificate is not even configured in puma so I doubt that traffic between the two is using SSL. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming u have already initializer for eventmachine

```
config/initializers/eventmachine.rb
Thread.new { EventMachine.run } unless EventMachine.reactor_running? && EventMachine.reactor_thread.alive?
```

nginx site conf:

```
upstream puma_project_production {
  server unix:/var/www/project/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  error_page 503 @503;

  server_name localhost project.local;
  root /var/www/project/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_project_production;

  location @puma_project_production {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://puma_project_production;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /var/www/project/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/project/shared/log/nginx.error.log;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {

    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location = /50x.html {
    root html;
  }

  location = /404.html {
    root html;
  }

  location @503 {
    error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
  }

  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }
location /websocket {
  proxy_pass http://puma_project_production;
           proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
  location ~ \.(php|rb)$ {
    return 405;
  }
}
```

Comment: nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Rails 4.2.1 on Puma 
Websockets rails NOT on standalone mode